# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting Android apps
- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1851).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2016](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/2067/community-promotion-ads-2016)

Answer (score 9):

[image: F-Droid: Certified open source apps]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Find apps by real-life categories!]

Comment: You also know this one from last year's promo. It has grown since, and proved as useful pointer not only here on Android.SE, but also over at SoftwareRecs.SE. Not to forget its extensive list of permissions with their explanations, the "search apps by permissions" feature, etc. :)

Answer (score 7):

[image: Car Dashboard - Car Home Application]

Comment: Same as last year, I am the developer of this application. The link is to my free version of the app, although I do make some money off sales of the Pro version. Thanks for your consideration of promoting my app! :)

Comment: Hm... I see Grooveshark there, you might want to update the screenshot. Or the app.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Droid Explorer - Open Source Rooted Android Device Manager]

Comment: As some may, or may not, know, I am the developer of this application. It is free, and open source. It has been around since August 2009 and still worked on, although updates are not as frequent as they used to be. Thank you for considering the promotion of Droid Explorer.

Comment: I alway wanted to try, but have no Windoze machine :( How far did you get with the Linux port (Mono, if I remember correctly)? Because if not, you might wish to alter the text to add the "Windows" in front of the "PC" :)

Comment: There were a couple people that were "helping" on the linux port. All of the core libraries compile to mono, the UI (an important part) is the only thing that did not, because of windows specific code. Which I knew. They did start on the UI for linux, but I am not sure how far they got. Once I get this new release out, I will focus some of my free time to getting it running on linux too, just for you Izzy :)

Answer (score 7):

[image: NOGAPPS: Help develop an Open Source replacement for Google Play Services]

Comment: Even though it is currently under development, I think it fits the criteria *"anything else your community would genuinely be interested in"*. many people who run Cyanogen/Replicant would love this.

Comment: A very good point, Nicolas (+1)! Running them as "substitute" on one of my active devices. They do pretty well!

Comment: PS: NOGAPPS meanwhile evolved to "µg" (or "microg" – think of microG ;) Multiple of its projects can be found at Github, e.g. UnifiedNLP (replacement for Google's location service).

Answer (score 6):

[image: AnkiDroid: Memorize everything!]

Answer (score 6):

[image: OsmAnd offline navigation GPS Android app]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Replicant: Fully open source Android distribution]

Comment: Yes, this is the project's official logo...

Answer (score 4):

[image: Izzy's Android-Handbuch (Deutsch/German)]

Comment: This is my eBook (same as from last years promo) in its latest version. I hope nobody minds that this year I chose the version for Amazon Kindle for this action, and you'll all support it nonetheless :)

Comment: How about using the cover of http://www.amazon.de/Android-Handbuch-Anwender-Izzys-Android-Handb%C3%BCcher-ebook/dp/B0071COWOU/ref=pd_sim_sbs_351_1/279-7089601-4705106?ie=UTF8&refRID=03ZK9C805H0ZAN5HY5G6 which is nicer? Is it just a different cover, or is it actually different content?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul this is the Amazon cover (of the eBook). The print version has a different cover, and unfortunately is not really up-to-date (about 2 years old). I will update the eBook on Amazon soon again – but I currently cannot say what time Franzis will bring out a new print edition (still waiting for feedback).

Comment: How about using the nice cover meanwhile? Would it be too confusing?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yes, it would: different book/edition, content is overlapping but not similar. Apart from which, using the other cover might violate copyrights of the publisher. And you make me feel sad saying my own cover-design is that bad, the cover is hurting your eyes, and you even would consider "just something else" better whether it matches or not :)

Answer (score 4):

[image: MAXS - Receive notifications and control your Android device over XMPP]

Comment: Made by me. Same as last year.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Wikivoyage, the free world travel guide, in your pocket]

Answer (score 3):

[See all questions with active bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/android.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://android.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: This is an adaption of [Community Promotion Ads - 2014](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1884); it will change dynamically. The size is _not_ a problem.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Showr web & RSS image widgets FREE on Google Play]